# Wordpress Query Current User ID

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I would like to echo mysql data based on the current user that's signed into Wordpress.

Example:

> SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE wp_users.id="current_signed_in_user"

So it will post all information from the table "wp_users" where the "wp_user.id" is the current signed in user's ID.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `<?php wp_get_current_user(); ?>` but you still need to see [ticket 14024](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14024)
to play with it .

Answer (score 1):

Resolved my issue by doing the following:

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$query ="SELECT * FROM wp_users, wp_devices, wp_readings WHERE wp_users.ID='$current_user->ID'

?>
```

:)